# How do I run code after a setTimeout() is run?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I need the

```
event.target.innerHTML = FULL_HEART
event.target.setAttribute('class', 'like-glyph activated-heart')
```

after the `displayError()` setTimeout interval is completed in the scenario that the `mimicServerCall()` catches an error.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const likeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.like-glyph');
  const modal = document.getElementById('modal');

  function displayError() {
    modal.removeAttribute('class');
    setTimeout(function(){ modal.setAttribute('class','hidden') }, 3000);
  };

  function likifyMe(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      if (event.target.innerHTML === EMPTY_HEART) {
        mimicServerCall().then(() => {}).catch(() => {displayError()});
        event.target.innerHTML = FULL_HEART
        event.target.setAttribute('class', 'like-glyph activated-heart')
      } else {
        event.target.innerHTML = EMPTY_HEART
        event.target.setAttribute('class', 'like-glyph')
      }
    });
  };

  likeButtons.forEach(button => {
    likifyMe(button)
  });

});
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: just put it in the setTimeout??

Comment: @MattOestreich The problem with that is, if the then function doesn't catch an error, the code won't run. I need the `event.target.innerHTML = FULL_HEART` and `event.target.setAttribute('class', 'like-glyph activated-heart')` to run if there is no error, and delayed if there is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage the following behavior of promise chaining detailed by [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining)

> It's possible to chain after a failure, i.e. a catch, which is useful to accomplish new actions even after an action failed in the chain.

You can rewrite the block in question to this (notice it's `.catch().then()`):

```
      if (event.target.innerHTML === EMPTY_HEART) {
        mimicServerCall().catch(() => displayError()).then(() => {
          event.target.innerHTML = FULL_HEART;
          event.target.setAttribute('class', 'like-glyph activated-heart');
        });
      } else {
```

Then, just have `displayError()` return a promise that resolves with the timeout:

```
  function displayError() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      modal.removeAttribute('class');
      setTimeout(() => {
        modal.setAttribute('class','hidden');
        resolve();
      }, 3000);
    });
  };
```

The resulting behavior is that your code to activate the heart is guaranteed to happen in the event of either success or failure, but if it did fail, it will wait the three seconds for the `setTimeout` to execute. This is thanks to promise chaining, which will wait for the promise returned by `displayError()` to resolve before executing the following `.then()` callback.

Comment: Note: the code `promise.catch(catchFn).then(thenFn)` will run `thenFn` even if `promise` gets rejected, unless the `catchFn` re-throws the exception. To make it called only if there weren't errors, it should be `promise.then(thenFn,catchFn)` or `promise.then(thenFn).catch(catchFn)`

Comment: @FZs That was the intended behavior the asker was requesting. The `thenFn` (in this case, to show the full heart) should run regardless of success or failure, *but* if it was a failure, it should wait for the failure message to vanish.

Comment: I  haven't really got what the question was, and I haven't wrote that you aren't correct, just a note (in case if the OP searched for an different solution).

Answer (score 1):

That's what a [callback](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced) is for:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const likeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.like-glyph');
  const modal = document.getElementById('modal');

  function displayError(callback) {
    modal.removeAttribute('class');
    setTimeout(function(){
        modal.setAttribute('class','hidden');
        callback();
    }, 3000);
  };

  function likifyMe(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      if (event.target.innerHTML === EMPTY_HEART) {
        mimicServerCall().then(() => {
            event.target.innerHTML = FULL_HEART;
            event.target.setAttribute('class', 'like-glyph activated-heart');
        }).catch(() => {
            displayError(function(){
                event.target.innerHTML = FULL_HEART;
                event.target.setAttribute('class', 'like-glyph activated-heart');
            });
        });
      } else {
        event.target.innerHTML = EMPTY_HEART
        event.target.setAttribute('class', 'like-glyph')
      }
    });
  };

  likeButtons.forEach(button => {
    likifyMe(button)
  });
});
```

Comment: The asker wants the full heart to be displayed regardless of if there was an error, but delayed by 3 seconds if there was an error. This answer currently only displays the full heart if there was an error and not otherwise.

Comment: Answer updated. Just put the success code in the then and the rejected code in the catch.